# Comparing Keys and Values in 2 Dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to take the aggregate numbers populated in one dictionary and compare both the keys and the values against keys and values in another dictionary to determine differences between the two. I can only conclude something like the following:

```
for i in res.keys():

    if res2.get(i):
        print 'match',i
    else:
        print i,'does not match'

for i in res2.keys():

    if res.get(i):
        print 'match',i
    else:
        print i,'does not match'

for i in res.values():

    if res2.get(i):
        print 'match',i
    else:
        print i,'does not match'

for i in res2.values():

    if res.get(i):
        print 'match',i
    else:
        print i,'does not match'
```

cumbersome and buggy...need help!

Comment: do both dictionaries have the same set of keys?

Comment: You can compare dictonaries with `res1 == res2`, do you also need to find out *which* parts are different?

Comment: `dict.keys` is a useless function, `a.keys() == list(a)` and a explicit list of keys is hardly ever useful anyways.

Comment: the dictionaries have different sets of keys (some matching) as well as different values (some matching)

Comment: @JochenRitzel: dict.keys() is way more explicit in its meaning than  list(dict).

Comment: I think you need to explain exactly what you mean by "comparing the values". Maybe show some example inputs and outputs. As it is, I don't think anyone really understands what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your second pair of loops is trying to do. Perhaps this is what you meant by "and buggy", because they're checking that the values in one dict are the keys in the other.

This checks that the two dicts contain the same values for the same keys. By constructing the union of the keys you can avoid looping twice, and then there are 4 cases to handle (instead of 8).

```
for key in set(res.keys()).union(res2.keys()):
  if key not in res:
    print "res doesn't contain", key
  elif key not in res2:
    print "res2 doesn't contain", key
  elif res[key] == res2[key]:
    print "match", key
  else:
    print "don't match", key
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like using the features of a set might work. Similar to Ned Batchelder:

```
fruit_available = {'apples': 25, 'oranges': 0, 'mango': 12, 'pineapple': 0 }

my_satchel = {'apples': 1, 'oranges': 0, 'kiwi': 13 }

available = set(fruit_available.keys())
satchel = set(my_satchel.keys())

# fruit not in your satchel, but that is available
print available.difference(satchel)
```

Comment: I am comparing differences in both the keys and the values so I decided to take your advice and amend to utilize iteritems as follows:                   `available=set(fruit_available.iteritems())` `satchel=set(my_satchel.iteritems())`                          `print available.difference(satchel), satchel.difference(available)`

Comment: note also that set(fruit_available.keys()) is equivalent (and perhaps more clear) than set(fruit_available)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by matching keys and values, but this is the simplest:

```
a_not_b_keys = set(a.keys()) - set(b.keys())
a_not_b_values = set(a.values()) - set(b.values())
```

Comment: Or `a.viewkeys() - b.viewkeys()` in Python 2.7, `a.keys() - b.keys()` in Python 3.x.

Comment: This would work, but would not discriminate different key pairings. Maybe do a key, value tuple set?

Comment: the dictionaries have different sets of keys, will this still work?