# Way to compare dictionary keys and values in python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have:

```
dictionary1 = {'Zookeeper': 3, 'Profit': 3, 'Collector': 3, 'Service': 3}
```

and

```
dictionary2 = {'Zookeeper': 2, 'Profit': 2}
```

The `dictionary2` may or may not be of same length and may or may not have the same values as of `dictionary1`. How do I write a Python function to compare these dictionaries and print the key from `dictionary2` which do not match values with `dictionary1`?

I came up with this which only matches the keys:

```
check_result = set(dictionary1.keys()) == set(dictionary2.keys())
```

But I need something more precise.

Comment: Refer to the first answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253493/comparing-keys-and-values-in-2-dictionaries

Comment: I think I already understood your question, check the answer and verify! and enjoy! cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I understood your question, this should do the work:

```
dictioanry1 = {'Zookeeper': 3, 'Profit': 3, 'Collector': 3, 'Service': 3}
dictionary2 = {'Zookeeper': 2, 'Profit': 2}

A = list(dictioanry1.keys())
B = list(dictionary2.keys())
commonKeys = set(A) - (set(A) - set(B))


for key in commonKeys:
    if(dictioanry1[key] != dictionary2[key]):
      print (key + ":" + str(dictionary2[key]) + " should be " + str(dictioanry1[key]))

   $ Profit:2 should be 3
   $ Zookeeper:2 should be 3
```

commonKeys Are the matching keys, ok? and A are the dictionary1.keys() (I put them into two variables to be more claire) so, I want to print all the values from dictionary2 (or B), but that not match, so, you ask if not belongs to the match-list

Comment: Damian, thanks for the answer I can get the keys, but I need the keys and values of those elements from dictionary2 which are not matching with dictionary1. Lets say dictionary2 have 'Zookeeper': 2, 'Profit': 2 but in dictionary1 these values are 'Zookeeper': 3, 'Profit': 3. So I wanna print like Zookeeper has 2 points but should have 3 and Profit has 2 points but should have 3

Comment: If you liked it great! thanks for the up voting! I have always loved to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I was solving a similar problem and used a solution that could be applicable here.

If you want to print the keys from dictionary2 which do not match values with dictionary1 you could try something like this

```
>>> dictionary1 = {'Zookeeper': 3, 'Profit': 3, 'Collector': 3, 'Service': 3}
>>> dictionary2 = {'Zookeeper': 2, 'Profit': 2}
>>> [ key for key, val in dictionary2.items() if dictionary1.get(key, None) != val ]
['Zookeeper', 'Profit']
```

That returns just the keys from dictionary2 that don't match values with dictionary1 as your question asked. I found it more beneficial, in my case, to return the keys and the values that don't match as a dictionary:

```
>>> dictionary1 = {'Zookeeper': 3, 'Profit': 3, 'Collector': 3, 'Service': 3}
>>> dictionary2 = {'Zookeeper': 2, 'Profit': 2}
>>> { key: val for key, val in dictionary2.items() if dictionary1.get(key, None) != val }
{'Zookeeper': 2, 'Profit': 2}
```